# Blank page with selenium/chromium/chromedriver

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, webdriver, chromium

I use a web scrape in python3, until yesterday it ran normally ... after a sudo apt update and upgrade the script stopped working on my server. I believe that it is with some incompatibility of versions, when loading the web page, does not even give a delay, responds instantly with the page blank.
Follow the versions that I have installed, according to the software website they are compatible.

```
python3-selenium 3.8.0+dfsg1-3
chromium-browser 80.0.3987.87-0ubuntu0.18.04.1).
chromedriver 80.0.3987.16
python3-pyvirtualdisplay 0.2.1-2
Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.15.0-88-generic x86_64)
```

My code:

```
import time
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium import webdriver
import selenium.webdriver.chrome.service as service
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
import csv


chromedriver_path = "/usr/bin/chromedriver"
chromium_path = "/usr/bin/chromium-browser"
service = service.Service(chromedriver_path)
service.start()
capabilities = {'chrome.binary': chromium_path}
opts = Options()
opts.binary_location = chromium_path
display = Display(visible=0, size=(1366, 800))
display.start()
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=opts)
driver.get('WEBSITE')
```

"Error":

```
>>> driver.get('URL')
>>>
>>> print (driver)
<selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver.WebDriver (session="10b0f9891b06979f90497b7bd0ef031c")>
>>> images = driver.find_elements_by_id("imgcap")
>>> print (images)
[]
```

Previously, it returned an image link.

Comment: Update the question with the error stack trace.

Comment: @DebanjanB 
I added the error